# Why is JPA-Query to delete Entities resulting in a com.objectdb TransactionRequiredException?

Tags: java, jpa, objectdb

I'm trying to delete the objects in the database.

My first attempt was:

```
 public void removeAll(){
    TypedQuery<anObject> query = em.createQuery(
            "DELETE FROM tablName",
            anObject.class);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

this gave me an exception so I had a look at the example on the objected site and updated my code to resemble theirs:

```
  public int removeAll(){
        int deleted = em.createQuery(
                "DELETE FROM tableName").executeUpdate();
    }
```

I'm getting the same exception:

```
com.objectdb.o._TransactionRequiredException: Attempt to run update query when no transaction is active
```

anyone know what I can do to solve?

Comment: Just in case anyone stumbles on this...I forgot the @Transactional notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added an answer here just in case someone else stumbles across this and it might help.

I had forgotten to add `@Transactional` notation.

The final code snippet looks like:

```
   @Transactional
public void removeAll(){
    TypedQuery<anObject> query = em.createQuery(
            "DELETE FROM tableName",
            anObject.class);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```